# Add VolumeName for all detected HDD's

Tags: windows, batch-file

ok so I have the following Windows Batch Script that pulls information for all connected storage devices (internal HDD / external USB drives) which is working just fine. However, I would like to add the name of each detected drive after where it says: `Volume x:\` like so: `Volume x:\ NAME OF HDD HERE`.

```
call :setESC

call :hdd-info

endlocal
echo. Press any key to exit &>nul timeout /t -1 &exit /B

REM - Setup ANSI Escape Character ------------------------------------------------
:setESC
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set ESC=%%b
  exit /B 0
)
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

:: - Get Storage / HDD Info ------------------------------------------------------
:hdd-info
:: Enable use of Unicode symbols
chcp 65001 >nul
set "GB=1073741824"
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%i in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe logicaldisk get deviceid^,freespace^,size^') do (for /f "tokens=1-3" %%j in ("%%i") do call :output %%j %%k %%l)
:: Disable Unicode symbols
chcp 1252 >nul
goto :eof

:output
if "%3"=="" (
  :: echo. Volume %optical_drive_letter%\ - %optical_drive_type% ^(%optical_drive_name%^)
goto :eof
)

for /f "tokens=1-4" %%i in (
  'mshta vbscript:Execute("CreateObject(""Scripting.FileSystemObject"").GetStandardStream(1).Write(FormatNumber(%3/%GB%, 2) & "" "" & FormatNumber((%3-%2)/%GB%, 2) & "" "" & FormatNumber(%2/%GB%, 2) & "" "" & Round((%3-%2)*50/%3)):Close"^)'
) do (
  set "size=%%i"
  set "used=%%j"
  set "free=%%k"
  set /a "nUsed=%%l, nFree=50-%%l"
)

echo( Volume %1\
echo( Total Size          : %size:~-10%GB
echo( Used Space          : %used:~-10%GB
echo( Free Space          : %free:~-10%GB
for /l %%i in (1 1 %nUsed%) do <nul set /p "=%ESC%[91m▓%ESC%[30m"
for /l %%i in (1 1 %nFree%) do <nul set /p "=%ESC%[92m▓%ESC%[30m"
echo( &echo(
goto :eof
:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The output is as follows: https://imgshare.io/image/list-hdds.rN55xP

Now, I also have the following that shows Optical drives as an example of the layout/information I need. IE: The name of the device adding after the Volume label.

**PLEASE NOTE**
This code is simply here as an example only.

```
:: - Get Optical Drive(s) Information -----------------------------------------------
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2,3 delims=," %%i in (
  '%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe logicaldisk where "drivetype=5" get Caption^ /format:csv'
) Do (
    set "optical_drive_letter=%%i"
)

for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=," %%a in (
  '%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe cdrom where "mediatype!=11" get name^,mediatype /format:csv'
) Do (
  set "optical_drive_type=%%a"
  set "optical_drive_name=%%b"
)

::echo( Volume %optical_drive_letter%\ 
::echo( %optical_drive_description%/%optical_drive_type% (%optical_drive_name%)
:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

echo( Volume %optical_drive_letter%\
echo( %optical_drive_type% (%optical_drive_name%)
echo(
```

So, to clarify the above displays the Volume label as does the initial script. However, it also shows the device name too.

https://imgshare.io/image/list-optical.rN5bbu

I know I can use `wmic.exe logicaldisk get Caption` to get this in CMD so can use something like this in a batch-file:

```
for /f "delims=^= tokens=2" %%a in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PATH Win32_DiskDrive GET Caption /format:list ^| findstr ^=') do set logicaldisk_name=%%a
```

My issue is that I do not know how to alter the original script to also get and show each devices name for **each** physical drive that is detected.

Can anyone please help with this as I seem to be pulling my hair out trying to make this work for all connected drives?

Full script can be found here: https://pastebin.com/q5QS4EmF

Many thanks,

Bri

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1,2*delims==" %%a in ('"%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe" logicaldisk get volumename /format:list') do if "%%b" neq "" echo %%b` or `for /f "skip=2tokens=2*delims=," %%a in ('"%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe" logicaldisk get volumename /format:csv') do echo %%a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the latest code which works perfectly:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=^=,# tokens=3,6" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe path Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition get Antecedent^,Dependent ^| find "="') do (
    set "disk[%%A]=%%B"
)

set "name=0"
set "GB=1073741824"
for /F "delims=^= tokens=2" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe path Win32_DiskDrive get Caption^,Index /value ^| find "="') do (
    if !name! EQU 0 (
        set hdd_name=%%A
        set "name=1"
    ) else (
        set "disk=%%A"
        for %%Q in (!disk: ^=!) do (
            for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-3 delims= " %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe LogicalDisk !disk[%%Q]! get DeviceId^,Freespace^,Size') do (
                for %%L in (%%I) do (
                    call :output %%I %%J %%K
                )
            )
        )
        SET "name=0"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without launching `WMIC.exe`, and `mshta.exe`, *(to call out to the `VBScript` engine)*; and to incorporate the much better `powershell.exe`, as offered in the other answer, here's an example [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) you could play around with, or learn from.

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile ^
 "Get-CimInstance -ClassName Cim_Diskdrive -PipelineVariable Disk | "^
 "ForEach-Object { $_ | Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Cim_DiskPartition -PipelineVariable Partition } | "^
 "ForEach-Object { $_ | Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Cim_LogicalDisk } | "^
 "Format-Table @{ Label = 'Letter';      Expression = { $_.DeviceId } }, "^
 "             @{ Label = 'Model';       Expression = { $Disk.Model.Trim() } }, "^
 "             @{ Label = 'Capacity';    Expression = { '{0:F0} GB' -F ($Disk.Size / 1000000000) } }, "^
 "             @{ Label = 'Partition';   Expression = { $Partition.Index } }, "^
 "             @{ Label = 'Label';       Expression = { $_.VolumeName } }, "^
 "             @{ Label = 'Size';        Expression = { '{0:F1} GiB' -F ($_.Size / 1GB) } }, "^
 "             @{ Label = 'Used';        Expression = { '{0:F1} GiB' -F (($_.Size - $_.FreeSpace) / 1GB) } }, "^
 "             @{ Label = 'FreeSpace';   Expression = { '{0:F1} GiB' -F ($_.FreeSpace / 1GB) } }, "^
 "             @{ Label = 'PercentFree'; Expression = { '{0:P1}' -F ($_.FreeSpace / $_.Size) } } -AutoSize"
@Pause
```

*I am aware that you are hoping for answers which you could just incorporate into your posted code submission, but in order to get the result you require, your entire script would need to be re-written and the resulting code would be significantly slower, more complex, and very difficult to understand and adapt.*

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to identify the drive letter, volume name, and disk usage properties for all attached logical disks.

1. Open PowerShell ISE.
2. Paste the following code in the script pane.
3. Press play (green arrow).

```
$DriveInformation = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object DeviceID, VolumeName, Description, @{'Name' = 'Total Size (GB)'; Expression = {[int]($_.Size/1GB)}}, @{'Name' = 'Used (GB)'; Expression = {[int](($($_.Size)-$($_.FreeSpace))/1GB)}}, @{'Name' = 'Available  (GB)'; Expression = {[int]($_.FreeSpace/1GB)}}
$DriveInformation
```

**Bonus**
If you want to export it to a file you can pipe the results of $DriveInformation to a specific format. Example is below;

```
$DriveInformation | Export-Csv "C:\temp\driveinformation.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
Start-Process "C:\temp\driveinformation.csv"
```

**Edit1:**
I should note that you can save the script as a .ps1 which can be run just like a batch file.

Comment: Firstly I'd like to say thank you to those that offered solutions. However, I think there may be some confusion as to what it is exactly that I need.

I already have a working script to show the **Total Size**, ** Used Space** and **Free Space** of all detected HDD's but it only shows the Drive letter. I also need it to show the **VolumeName** too. I know how to get this information (```wmic.exe logicaldisk get volumename```) but do not know how to incorporate this information in to the existing script to make it list each new name for each of the detected drives.

Comment: Please Note: I only included the separate script for the Optical Drive (and image) to show a proposed layout for what I require from the first script that displays information for physical drives. To clarify more: It currently shows ```Volume C:\``` but I need it to show (for example) ```Volume C:\ Samsung SSD 840 EVO``` and for the next one it finds, ```Volume D:\ 'HDD name here'``` etc...

Comment: @Bri, are you sure what it is you are looking for? I ask because in your initial comment above, you are talking about the name of the volume, and in your follow up comment, the model name of the disk which holds the volume. Are you saying that `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe" LogicalDisk Where "DeviceID='C:'" Get VolumeName /Format:'List'` returns `VolumeName=Samsung SSD 840 EVO`, i.e. you have specifically labelled your volume `Samsung SSD 840 EVO`, which also happens to be the model name of the disk upon which that volume resides.

Comment: Compo, The original script shows each 'volume label', IE the Drive letter. What I need to do is then have it also automatically add the name of the drive.

Comment: Please see the following: https://imgshare.io/image/capture.rNSgtg

You'll see that each hard drive shows only ```Volume C:\```. However, I would like each to show as previously stated with the name of the device too like the separate bit of code that shows Volume F:\ DVD Writer (then name here).

I assume I just need to add the correct command to get the name of the device to this but I do not know what it is to get the name: ```wmic.exe logicaldisk get deviceid^,freespace^,size^') do (for /f "tokens=1-3" %%j in ("%%i") do call :output %%j %%k %%l)```

Comment: @Bri, What I am telling you is that it is very very unlikely that your `VolumeName` string for your `C:` `Caption` is `Samsung SSD 840 EVO`, because that is the model name of the disk. *Only a fool would use the model name of a disk drive for the volume name when that device could contain multiple partitions/volumes, (you would end up with multiple volumes, all with the same name/label)*. Please look at everything on this page, and understand that you appear to be the only person who currently knows exactly what you mean. Until you can change that, you are unlikely to receive your wanted help.

Comment: This is why I am asking for help as I do not know the command / name of the bit I need to get each HDD name. All I want it to do is show the equivalent formatting/detail for each HDD as I have for the optical drive: Volume x:\ then I assume 'Physical Disk (name (or model as you state) of device.

Comment: I'm not sure why my post was downvoted. I understand that you want the drive letter and volume name in the same output. The script I provided gives both and the description. The description was added because the VolumeName doesn't show anything on some of the drive letters, unless you manually right-click rename them. [link](https://imgur.com/nP6t9np)

Comment: Using ```wmic logicaldisk``` I have been through every single item listed trying to get the name of my HDD - In this case a Samsung Evo as stated already. I would have thought the term would be 'manufacturer' but obviously this is not the case.

All I need to know is how to show this information and add it to the following code: ```wmic.exe logicaldisk get deviceid^,freespace^,size^') do (for /f "tokens=1-3" %%j in ("%%i") do call :output %%j %%k %%l)``` as another variable. I have also googled for like 3 days and found nothing.

Comment: 6ark, I did not downvote your post but I need this in batch not powershell as it needs to integrate with the existing script.

Comment: I believe you were looking for the disk friendly name. I didn't see any way to tie them together with the given properties, maybe you can?
`Get-Disk | Select-Object -Property disknumber, friendlyname, @{'name' = 'Total Size (GB)'; Expression = {[int]($_.size/1gb)}}, @{'name' = 'Allocated Size (GB)'; Expression = {[int]($_.allocatedsize/1gb)}}`

Comment: After a little more head scratching it seems it is the ```caption``` of each drive I require adding to the existing script.

Comment: The caption parameter appears to just be another drive letter from my view. You can look at all the parameters from the original answer by typing;
`Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object -Property *`

Comment: 6ark I'm not using PowerShell - I'm using Windows Batch as posted in the original question. ```wmic PATH Win32_DiskDrive GET Caption``` in Command Prompt gives me the following:
```C:\Users\brian>wmic PATH Win32_DiskDrive GET Caption``
```Caption```
```USB  SanDisk 3.2Gen1 USB Device```
```Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB```

Comment: However, ```for /f "delims=^= tokens=2" %%a in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PATH Win32_DiskDrive GET Caption /format:list ^| findstr ^=') do set logicaldisk_name=%%a```
```echo HDD Name: %logicaldisk_name%``` shows ```HDD Name: Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB``` - I just need the above code for caption to be integrated within ```for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%i in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe logicaldisk get deviceid^,freespace^,size^') do (for /f "tokens=1-3" %%j in ("%%i") do call :output %%j %%k %%l)```.

Comment: ```for /f "delims=^= tokens=2" %%a in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PATH Win32_DiskDrive GET Caption /format:list ^| findstr ^=') do set logicaldisk_name=%%a```

```for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%i in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe logicaldisk get deviceid^,freespace^,size^') do (for /f "tokens=1-3" %%j in ("%%i") do echo %%j %logicaldisk_name% %%k %%l)```

This of course shows incorrectly. IE:
```C: Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB 179330637824 249403711488```
```F: Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB```
```H: Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB 50600804352 123030798336```

Comment: I need:

```C: Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB 179330637824 249403711488```
```F: DVD Writer (HL-DT-ST DVD-RAM GHC0N)```
```H: SanDisk 3.2Gen1 USB 50600804352 123030798336```